# Retrieve documents where birthday is today

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've the following collection called "members":

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a477681bbe5f506e68d29b7"),
    "name" : "mario", 
    "surname" : "rossi", 
    "email" : "test@gmail.com", 
    "birth" : ISODate("1998-12-29T23:00:00Z"), 
    "fc" : null, "expires" : ISODate("2018-12-29T23:00:00.183Z")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a477943bbe5f506e68d29b8"),
    "name" : "mario", 
    "surname" : "rossi", 
    "email" : "test@gmail.com", 
    "birth" : new Date, 
    "fc" : null, "expires" : ISODate("2018-12-29T23:00:00.570Z")
}
```

Now I want to return only name, surname and email of members whose birthday is today. Do you know what query can I use?

Thank you

Comment: I've tried this: `db.members.aggregate([{ $project: { _id: 0, email: "$email", "name": "$name", dayOfYear: {$dayOfYear: "$birth"}} }, {$match: {dayOfYear: {$eq: {$dayOfYear: ISODate("2018-12-30T23:00:00.350Z")}}}} ]);` but it doesn't work (it returns a empty list).. but if I try to substitute the $dayOfYear operator with the day (e.g. 363) it works

Comment: You can try `db.members.find({"$expr":{"$eq": [{"$dayOfYear": ISODate("2018-12-30T23:00:00.350Z")}, {"$dayOfYear": "$birth"}]}});` in 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var currentDate = new Date(),
    date = currentDate.getDate(),
    month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth returns (0-11)

db.members.aggregate([
{
    $project:
    {
        name: 1,
        surname: 1,
        email: 1,
        date:
        {
            $dayOfMonth: '$birth'
        },
        month:
        {
            $month: '$birth'
        }
    }
},
{
    $match:
    {
        date: date, // Current date of the month
        month: month // Current month
    }
}]);
```